# iOS split string

Tags: ios, iphone, string, formatting

ex1) `a:3:{i:0;s:6:"Apple";i:1;s:4:"Google";}`

ex2) `a:2:{i:0;s:13:"Area";i:1;s:10:"Place";i:2;s:10:"Location";}`

ex3) `a:4:{i:0;s:6:"Cool";i:1;s:6:"Nice";i:2;s:6:"Awesome";i:3;s:6:"Wonderful";}`

ex4)  ...

ex5)  ...

this is Answers about our Survey. i received string from server to iPhone. something like that.

a:%d is words count about answer.

i:%d is Index about words. it is increase.

s:%d is length about word.

i don't know what will be word inside double quotation marks. (random)

i understood componentsSeparatedByString.
how to get words inside double quotation marks?

Comment: `componentsSeperatedByString` will get you an array of `NSString`, which will include words like `"Apple"`, `"Google"`, etc.  So this question isn't about splitting a string, it's about formatting a string.  You need to ignore the fact that you're going to start by splitting the string and focus on parsing the quotes off the string.

Comment: the string above is encoded json , simply decode it. no need to split and start manipulate.

Answer (score 4):

```
[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
```

This will get rid of the quotes.  Combine this with my comment and you've got it all figured out.

```
NSMutableArray *arrSplitString = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[originalString componentsSeperatedByString:@";"]];
for(int i=0; i<[arrSplitString count]; ++i) {
    arrSplitString[i] = [arrSplitString[i] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
}
```

If the `;` isn't the `char` you need to split on, you'll need to change that to the `char` you need to split on.  If you need to split on multiple delimiters, then you'll want to look at the `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet` method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. can you write in detail?

Comment: i am sorry but 'NSMutableArray' declares the selector 'size'

Comment: @Lee It's `count`.  I had the `for` loop wrong when you looked at it, but I've fixed it since.

Comment: Thank you for your kind but i am beginner. so can you help me until NSLog? ex) obj.option_answer is my string.